# How to get current component loaded by the router (in parent or child) in Angular?

Tags: angular, angular-router

Suppose we have an angular routes defined as:

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        component: HomeComponent
    },
    {
        path: '/user',
        component: UserComponent,
        children: [
            {
                path: 'edit-profile',
                component: EditProfileComponent
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I want to identify the current component loaded by the router.

So if a user visits `/user/edit-profile` then I want `EditProfileComponent` as a string or object and if a user visit `/` then I want `HomeComponent`.

Answer (score 0):

Use [ActivatedRoute](https://angular.io/api/router/ActivatedRoute) service which provides access to information about a route associated with a component that is loaded in an outlet. Then use router events which will be triggered whenever the route changes.

```
constructor(private router: Router, private route: ActivatedRoute) {}
this.router.events.subscribe(event => {
      if(event instanceof NavigationEnd){
      console.log(this.route.component.name);
      }
    })
```

[Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-router-event-tnvxsj)

Comment: There is no property called name.

Comment: But the solution does not work, since name property does not exists at all.

Comment: Activated route do have property called component which is type  component: Type<any> | string | null, but if you console it you can see it has read only property name

Comment: sorry, it is not true.

Comment: this.route.component is a function.

Comment: Ya i agree its a function, if you expand that you can see the name property